# Parallax effect - force text block to behave like background-attachment: fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to create a simple parallax effect where each `100vh` section scrolls up to reveal the next section (new background color, background image, and text block) while keeping the text block fixed relative to its parent container.

I've put together a static example of what I'm trying to achieve using screenshots of each section: [static example](https://codepen.io/reidgannah/full/pLYjLw/). Of course I'd like the content to be dynamic rather than flat images.

Here's a simple version of my code thus far:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
}
p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
section.first {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1057);
}
section.first .content {
  background-color: rgba(74, 180, 220, .85);
}
section.second {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1067);
}
section.second .content {
  background-color: rgba(103, 198, 180, .85)
}
section.third {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1033);
}
section.third .content {
  background-color: rgba(5, 123, 188, .85);
}
section.fourth {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500?image=1063);
}
section.fourth .content {
  background-color: rgba(187, 216, 100, .85)
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;  
}
.copy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.button {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: .2s ease all;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <section class="first">
  <div class="content">
   <div class="copy">
    <h2>Header 1  </h2>
    <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section class="second">
  <div class="content">
   <div class="copy">
    <h2>Header 2</h2>
    <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section class="third">
  <div class="content">
   <div class="copy">
    <h2>Header 3</h2>
    <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section class="fourth">
  <div class="content">
   <div class="copy">
    <h2>Call to action</h2>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
```

The parallax effect is achieved using CSS `background-attachment: fixed` and works just fine; the trouble is with the text blocks. I'd like to keep them "pinned" in place and centered within their section. If they are set to `position: fixed` they of course overlap each other and all show up in the first section. If they are set to any other position attribute, they will simply scroll like any other element.

Now, I realize that setting an element's position to fixed means it can no longer be relative to its parent element; it escapes the flow so to speak, but I'm trying to determine if there's a way to achieve the effect with some advanced CSS or even a JS alternative.

I've tried numerous HTML/CSS combinations (wrappers within wrappers, etc.) and I've also attempted various javascript solutions such as rellax, jarallax, and ScrollMagic, but everything I've come across is far too robust for my needs. I've searched around for the better part of the day hoping to find an example of what I'm attempting, but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998036/how-to-create-image-scrolling-blend-effect-with-css/48998170#48998170) I did a similar effect with image and using some JS so am going to use the same technique to reproduce this using content as I don't think there is a pure CSS solution. So the idea is to simulate the fixed position by using absolute position and adjusting the top property dynamically on scroll.

Here is an example where I also adjusted some of the CSS to make it easier. I will also rely on CSS variables to make the JS code very light so we can manage everything with CSS.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scroll = window.scrollY || window.scrollTop || document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--scroll-var', scroll + "px");
}
```

```css
:root {
  --scroll-var: 0px
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  position: relative; /*Mandatory for the overflow effect*/
  height: 100vh;
}

section.first {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(74, 180, 220, .85), rgba(74, 180, 220, .85)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1057);
}

section.first .content {
  /* the first section so top start from 0*/
  top: calc((0 * 100vh) + var(--scroll-var));
}

section.second {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(103, 198, 180, .85), rgba(103, 198, 180, .85)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1067);
}

section.second .content {
  /* the second section so we need to remove the height of top section
     to have the same position so -100vh and we do the same for the other sections  
  */
  top: calc((-1 * 100vh) + var(--scroll-var));
}

section.third {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(5, 123, 188, .85), rgba(5, 123, 188, .85)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1033);
}

section.third .content {
  top: calc((-2 * 100vh) + var(--scroll-var));
}

section.fourth {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(187, 216, 100, .85), rgba(187, 216, 100, .85)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500?image=1063);
}

section.fourth .content {
  top: calc((-3 * 100vh) + var(--scroll-var));
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.copy {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.button {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: .2s ease all;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="first">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Header 1 </h2>
        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="second">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="third">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Header 3</h2>
        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="fourth">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Call to action</h2>
        <a class="button">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Very nice use of calc and css variable

Comment: Beautiful solution. Thank you so much. I'm not as well versed in javascript though so can you clarify one thing: Is `var scroll = window.scrollY || window.scrollTop || document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop;` a set of redundancies/fallbacks? In testing, I removed one or two at a time and everything seemed to continue working as expected so I was curious.

Comment: @ReidGannah yes you got it ;) there is some fallback to make it work with IE and old browser ... if you seach on google how to get the scroll position you will get this kind of answer but like you did you are not obliged to use them all, you can remove some of them ;)

Comment: @Temani Afif, sorry for the lapse in my follow up, but do you have any ideas for improving the performance of this technique for browsers other than Chrome? I'm experiencing issues in my production environment when viewing in Firefox, Safari and pretty much anything except for Chrome. The JS works, but the text block jumps around quite a bit when scrolling. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have put up a little snippet, that works. But you need to figure out the exact math behind positioning yourself. And of course take care of the details

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      // get the position of my first slide, so I know where did I move
      var rect = $(".first")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
      
      // get height of viewport
      var screenHeight = $( window ).height();
      
      // setting offset for every .copy element on page, so they share
      // the same offset from top (are on top of each other)
      // Now you just need to figure out exact math here
      $(".copy").offset({ top: screenHeight*1.5-rect.bottom});
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  
  /* added overflow hidden, so that my boxes don't flow out of the slide */
  overflow: hidden;
}

section.first {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1057);
}

section.first .content {
  background-color: rgba(74, 180, 220, .85);
}

section.second {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1067);
}

section.second .content {
  background-color: rgba(103, 198, 180, .85)
}

section.third {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1033);
}

section.third .content {
  background-color: rgba(5, 123, 188, .85);
}

section.fourth {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500?image=1063);
}

section.fourth .content {
  background-color: rgba(187, 216, 100, .85)
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.copy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.button {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: .2s ease all;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <section class="first">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Header 1 </h2>
        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="second">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="third">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Header 3</h2>
        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="fourth">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Call to action</h2>
        <a class="button">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: I think we can optimize some of the js code like using `100vh` instead of calling the height function ... and can you explain the `1.5` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif   That was just random multiplier, that made it work :-) Yours is way more elegant solution

Comment: i am the other answer :) and i will give the explanation ... the element on where you need to apply top need to be centred so we need to have the `top:50%` --> so 100vh is the height of screen - the bottom to get the scroll of the first + 0.5 of 100vh which is 50% of the centring ;) it's not random it's math :)