# Scrolling blend effect - performance issues in all browsers except Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

With the help received in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763949/parallax-effect-force-text-block-to-behave-like-background-attachment-fixed), I'm utilizing a bit of JS along with CSS variables to achieve a "blend" effect when scrolling through a page as seen in [this working example](https://codepen.io/reidgannah/pen/eKpNbK).

The solution is great... but only in Chrome. I've begun to implement this in my project though and testing in other browsers revealed severe performance issues, specifically the content block jumps around while scrolling. I revisited my test example in Firefox & Safari and found the same issues.

So my question is simply, what can I do to improve the performance of this effect? I've done quite a bit of searching to find an alternative way to pull off this effect, but no luck thus far. Perhaps there are modifications I can make to my JS to account for these issues though.

I've included my code below for reference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scroll = window.scrollY || window.scrollTop || document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--scroll-var', scroll + "px");
}
```

```css
:root {
  --scroll-var: 0px
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  position: relative; /*Mandatory for the overflow effect*/
  height: 100vh;
}

section.first {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(74, 180, 220, .85), rgba(74, 180, 220, .85)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1057);
}

section.first .content {
  /* the first section so top start from 0*/
  top: calc((0 * 100vh) + var(--scroll-var));
}

section.second {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(103, 198, 180, .85), rgba(103, 198, 180, .85)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1067);
}

section.second .content {
  /* the second section so we need to remove the height of top section
     to have the same position so -100vh and we do the same for the other sections  
  */
  top: calc((-1 * 100vh) + var(--scroll-var));
}

section.third {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(5, 123, 188, .85), rgba(5, 123, 188, .85)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1033);
}

section.third .content {
  top: calc((-2 * 100vh) + var(--scroll-var));
}

section.fourth {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(187, 216, 100, .85), rgba(187, 216, 100, .85)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500?image=1063);
}

section.fourth .content {
  top: calc((-3 * 100vh) + var(--scroll-var));
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.copy {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.button {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: .2s ease all;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="first">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Header 1 </h2>
        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="second">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="third">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Header 3</h2>
        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="fourth">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Call to action</h2>
        <a class="button">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh, so my solution is bad then :p

Comment: So I have been playing around with this for a bit now. Can replicate your problem in FF but haven't found a solution. You should read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects

Comment: @TemaniAfif Haha, I think your solution is brilliant, honestly. I just hope there's a workaround for performance improvement. Any ideas?

Comment: @Geuis, that was a good read to understand why these issues are occurring... thank you. Unfortunately, the only course of action detailed in that article is to find a CSS alternative (if I'm understanding everything correctly), which I don't think is possible for this particular scenario. Were there any other takeaways though that you think I should consider?

Comment: yes, only chrome support my brillant solution, the other browser still need to be improved :p ...I have tried few things and still the same issue :/ even if I remove the complex calculation and CSS var

Comment: I have undeleted my answer, you can have a look at it, even without complex stuffs it's not working fine

Comment: @ReidGannah So the basic underlying problem is that Firefox doesn't emit as many scroll events as Chrome does. Going to see if I can demo a fix.

Comment: @Geuis, I understand. Let me know if you make any progress. I haven't found any viable alternatives at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I think by simplifing the logic of calcuting the top value you can fix your issues. You can use a fixed top value for each section then adjust `margin-top` for all of them.

You can also get rid of the CSS variable:

```js
var all = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
var l = all.length;

window.onscroll = function() {
  var scroll = window.scrollY || window.scrollTop || document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop;
  for(var i=0;i<l;i++)
   all[i].style.marginTop=scroll + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  position: relative; /*Mandatory for the overflow effect*/
  height: 100vh;
}

section.first {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(74, 180, 220, .85), rgba(74, 180, 220, .85)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1057);
}

section.first .content {
  /* the first section so top start from 0*/
  top:0;
}

section.second {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(103, 198, 180, .85), rgba(103, 198, 180, .85)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1067);
}

section.second .content {
  /* the second section so we need to remove the height of top section
     to have the same position so -100vh and we do the same for the other sections  
  */
  top: -100vh;
}

section.third {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(5, 123, 188, .85), rgba(5, 123, 188, .85)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500/?image=1033);
}

section.third .content {
  top: -200vh;
}

section.fourth {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(187, 216, 100, .85), rgba(187, 216, 100, .85)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/500?image=1063);
}

section.fourth .content {
  top:-300vh;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top:0px;
}

.copy {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.button {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: .2s ease all;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="first">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Header 1 </h2>
        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="second">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="third">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Header 3</h2>
        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="fourth">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="copy">
        <h2>Call to action</h2>
        <a class="button">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```