# Fixing text to image while creating parallax scrolling effect

Tags: html, css, text, css-position, parallax

I am trying to create parallax scrolling effect, the image works well, but I have some text over the image, and I want the text to be "fixed" to image - and then make the rest of website overlap it. The text should be at the same position while scrolling, until you scroll out of image. If I use position: fixed, it just keeps there over the whole website.

```css
p {
  font-size: 50px;
}

header {
  background-image: url("https://wallpapercave.com/wp/DtslnrT.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size:55px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.text{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="text">
  Sample text
  </div>
</header>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 50px;
}

header {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/BVyNv0o.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size:55px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.text{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="text">
  </div>
</header>
<p>
HOW IT SHOULD WORK

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Comment: something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763949/parallax-effect-force-text-block-to-behave-like-background-attachment-fixed/49764361#49764361 ?

Comment: looks good, but the div is showing from bottom, I want it to scroll normally over the first one - it should look the same, as the text was written on image - I have added how I want it to look like, the text is written on image here, or if I set it to position: fixed, it's also good - until you scroll down to the next div, the text remains at the top above the div

Comment: exactly what I did, my example is elaborated but As you can see the text is fixed in the first layer and also the second layer so simply keep the logic of the first layer