# Text is shaking after using useEffect in Next JS

Tags: javascript, next.js, use-effect

I want to build my client website like [ssk.com](https://ssk.com) and I tried to change the JQuery code from this [jsfiddle.net/LmkwxkfL](https://jsfiddle.net/LmkwxkfL) to the code. but seems I failed to translate the code.

Result: text is shaking after scrolling

This is my code:

```
const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
});

function handleScroll() {
    setScroll(
        window.scrollY ||
        window.scrollTop ||
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop,
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--scroll-var", scroll + "px")
    );
}
```

I don't know what is missing, but it makes all my text shaky after rendering it and starts after scrolling the page.

So sorry I'm a newbie here.

Comment: Welcome to SO. what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: i want build my client website like this https://www.ssk.com/, and try to change the jquery code from this http://jsfiddle.net/LmkwxkfL/ to the code above. but seems i failed to translate the code.

Comment: You just copy-pasted that from the question. @whygee wanted you to elaborate, so please elaborate.

Comment: The website you linked `ssk.com` is using [GSAP](https://greensock.com/) to make the animation you seem to try to achieve. I would definitely recommend you check that out instead of trying to convert jquery code to React since its not the same philosophy.

Comment: its not copy-paste from my question. i edited the question after i realized that @whygee asking for that. sorry all.

Comment: @whygee thanks for your explanation.  but i find this answer here. i try but confused how to use this in next js. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763949/parallax-effect-force-text-block-to-behave-like-background-attachment-fixed

Comment: Many things are wrong here. Firstly, provide an empty dependency array to your `useEffect`, so that it doesn't register a new event listener each time your scroll. Second, move your handleScroll to inside useEffect or outside your component. This will prevent creating a new reference to handleScroll each time the component state changes.

Comment: @brc-dd can you fixed the code form me? i would very thankful. i try to use GSAP right now. but seems must learn it first.