# Simulate change of color when div overlays another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed div, which scroll over certain elements.

When the div is over a certain div, I wan't it to have a certain color and a certain image. When it's over another div, I want it to change color.

[image]

[Basic live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c2a4jg95/8/)

I'm pretty sure that for this i will need two divs, one is hidden.

I played around with `z-index`, but this doesn't seem, to be solvable with such basic stuff.

[More complex example.](http://jsfiddle.net/c2a4jg95/22/)

I play around with the property this:

```
.two {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 250;
}
```

But the orders seem contradictory,

If both sizes are fixed, I could use js to do some magic to the height of the pixels of the element related to the scrolled pic.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost close thinking about using two divs. The trick is that you need to make them in different containers and rely on `overflow:hidden` and use `position:absolute` intead of fixed in this case but you need some JS to control the position so it behaves like fixed:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scroll = window.scrollY || window.scrollTop || document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--scroll-var', scroll+"px");
}
```

```css
:root {
 --scroll-var:0;
}

.container {
  height: 150px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top:var(--scroll-var,20px);
}

.only-one{
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.only-two{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-top:-150px; /*The height of the previous section*/
}

.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
  
}
.one {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay one">
    
  </div>
  <div class="fixed only-one">
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay two">
    
  </div>
    <div class="fixed only-two">
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay three">
    
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay four">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a related question where I have done a similar effect : [How to create image scrolling blend effect with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998036/how-to-create-image-scrolling-blend-effect-with-css/48998170#48998170)

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks a bunch, I'm checking out the code and I'll accept a little later.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the color to react to the background color you can use [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode):

> The mix-blend-mode CSS property describes how an element's content
>   should blend with the content of the element's direct parent and the
>   element's background.

**Note:** not supported by IE/Edge

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: lightblue;
  mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
}

.one {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container one">
  <div class="fixed">
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container two"></div>
<div class="container three"></div>
<div class="container four"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I'm looking for, since the control over the way it blends is to basic. I need certain specific colors when it's over the first div and others for when it's over the other.

Comment: And while I'm aiming for modern browsers, edge should be included.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

https://jsbin.com/wozedar/edit?html,css,js,output

or more to the point use this function as a base for what you want:

```
function isOnTopOf(a, b) {
  var fixedCoord = a.getBoundingClientRect(); 
  var bgCoord = b.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (fixedCoord.top + fixedCoord.height >= bgCoord.top) {
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

To compare elements, in your case you would probably do something like this on each scroll:

```
var fixed = document.querySelector(".fixed-div");
var div1 = document.querySelector(".div--1");

if (isOnTopOf(fixed, div2)) {
   fixed.classList.add("fixed-div--light");
}
```

The function [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://jsbin.com/wozedar/edit?html,css,js,output) gets you the relevant info from which you can determine whether objects are above, below or on top of each other.

Just add an event listener to the window object and compare the positions on each scroll and you're good to go. You could maybe look into [throttling](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf) the scroll function if you want to do more complex stuff, but this jsbin should get you going.