# Dynamic CSS color depending on background

Tags: css

[image: Dynamicly changing colour depending on background]

The color of the icons are being changed depending on the background from black to white.

I can't figure it out from the inspector tool on how this is done. Guessing its done with `mix-blend-mode`?

Can someone explain to me how to do this?

This is the website where I found this: https://www.dennissnellenberg.nl/en.

Comment: Tried using `miz-blend-mode: difference` but it only works if my body is black and the element is white. When it encounters any white colour, the element converts to black. But can't make the opposite happen, like the example above.

Comment: Why is this tagged as reactjs?

Comment: You can find many examples if you search for `slip scroll`. Related QA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998036/how-to-create-image-scrolling-blend-effect-with-css/48998170#48998170

Answer (score 0):

You're right - it's `mix-blend-mode`.

It introduces a number of options to add blending features - previously the realm of Photoshop or other graphic design programs. It takes a number of options, including difference, which is an inversion blending mode, creating the black/white change.

Browsers are now starting to support this - see https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode for support.

See also `background-blend-mode` for the equivalent for background images.

Answer (score 0):

It was done with `mix-blend-mode: difference` which basically reverses the colors based on the background.

**Html:**

```
<div class="background-wrapper">
   <p class="mix-blend-item"> Hello </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mix-blend-item {
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    color: white;
}

.background-wrapper {
    background: black; // change it to white to invert mix-blend-item color
}
```

Comment: It works that way, however I want a black item on a white background to blend in when it finds any black backgrounds. This is my code right now. ``     <div
        style={{
          position: 'fixed',
          fontSize: 30,
          mixBlendMode: 'difference',
          color: 'black',
        }}
      >
        Yo yo
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'black',
          height: 800,
          width: '100%',
        }}
      />``

Comment: Great! I hope it help you. :)